# Why do only some of my js work when I switch cases with php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, switch-statement

I cannot figure out for the life of me why only some of my js works.

I am using a switch-case in my php files.

Both "content_allinboxes.php" and "content_emails.php" can recognize "app.v2.js".

However, "content_allinboxes.php" also uses "jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" & "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" but they aren't recognized.

What am I doing wrong? I have been at this for hours and can't figure it out.

(Note: The two javascript files works if I do not put "content_allinboxes.php" in the switch-case.)

---

Here is how the switch contents are called:

```
<div id="displayLoading"><img src="images/account/loading_indicator.gif"/></div>
<div id="displayContent" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

Here is the switch-case codes. This file is called "content_load.php":

```
<?php
switch($_GET['id']) {
    case 'feeds_allinboxes':
        $content = 'content_allinboxes.php';
        break;
    case 'feeds_emails':
        $content = 'content_emails.php';
        break;
    case 'feeds_chats':
        $content = 'test_print.html';
        break;
    case 'feeds_phones':
        $content = 'test_print.html';
        break;
    default:
        $content = 'test_print.html';
} 

include($content);
?>
```

Here is the javascript that runs the switch-cases. The file is called "switchcontent.min.js":

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function () {
    var switches = document.getElementsByClassName('switches');
    for (var i = 0; i < switches.length; i++) {
        $(switches[i].id).onclick = function () {
            getContent(this.id);
        }
    }
});

function getContent(id) {
    var url = 'pages/content_load.php';
    var rand   = Math.random(9999);
    var pars   = 'id=' + id + '&rand=' + rand;
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request( url, {method: 'get', parameters: pars, onLoading: showLoad, onComplete: showResponse} );
}

function showLoad () {
    $('displayContent').style.display = 'none';
    $('displayLoading').style.display = 'block';
}

function showResponse (originalRequest) {
    var newData = originalRequest.responseText;
    $('displayLoading').style.display = 'none';
    $('displayContent').style.display = 'block';        
    $('displayContent').innerHTML = newData;
}
```

Here are the footer javascripts:

```
<script src="js/app.v2.js"></script>
<script src="js/switchcontent.js"></script>
<script src="js/switchcontent.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" cache="false"></script>
```

Comment: Reverse the order of JavaScript Source adding, first add jQuery min, then jQuery ui touch, then other JS filles reference in your JS and finally your js. 
PS: check browser console to see error details.

Comment: Dang, I thought it would work. No dice. The JS order shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: JS order matter, http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript  go through this.

Comment: Set this type="text/javascript" in your script tag if you haven't mentioned <!DOCTYPE html> ...! html5 doesnt need this  type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="js/switchcontent.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/switchcontent.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.v2.js"></script>
```

Reverse the order of JavaScript Source adding, first add jQuery min, then jQuery ui touch, then other JS filles reference in your JS and finally your js.

PS: check browser console to see error details.

Comment: Your right order does matter. However, still no dice. I tried different orders (including yours), nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard order of imports :

```
 <script src="YOUR_JQUERY_VERSION_.js"></script>
 <script src="JQUERY_UI_VERSION.js"></script> 
 <script src="OTHER_JQUERY_LIBRARIES.js"></script> 
 <script src="YOUR_OWN_LIBRARY.js"></script>
```

and your :

```
<script src="js/switchcontent.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/switchcontent.js"></script>
```

is basically the same. so delete either one of the two.